# Using both bottom navigation and tabs for an android app

Tags: navigation, mobile-application, material-design

I was told it's a bad practice to have both bottom navigation and tabs in the same screen, but I'm not finding any information about why, and what can I use instead of tab bars in Material Design. The Google Play app has both for some reason.

I'm developing an app for Android and my home screen looks like this. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a section about exactly this topic in the [Material Guidelines](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation#usage):

[image]

> **Caution**
> Combining bottom navigation and tabs may cause confusion, as their relationship to the content may be unclear. Tabs share a common subject, whereas bottom navigation destinations are top-level and disconnected from each other.

Basically it's simply about confusion. If you can make it clear enough then it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You have to make it clear global vs local navigation. It's unclear in the image above, however, if the tabs are local nav, then having them within the white background body would be much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

i don't advice you to do that it's a UX disaster users will be very confuser if you are willing to base on tab more likely use **Burger Menu**